# D3 - adding dynamic data to tick labels

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization

[D3 tick labels missing dynamic data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIOZU.png)

I'm calculating the average load factors of each types of airplanes from a database. I end up with the following array:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => 319
            [value] => 92.1418589744
            [count] => 402
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 320
            [value] => 90.2765555556
            [count] => 454
        )

)
```

I'm trying to display the count value right under the name of the aircraft. Is it possible to do that simply with an ordinal scale?

```
    var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                  .domain(dataArray.map(function(d) 
{ return d.name; }))
                  .rangeRoundBands([YaxisLPadding + YaxisRPadding, SVGwidth - margin]);
```

Answer (score 0):

An ordinal scales map a [single value](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/c36befc7361cd61538294048c387a8a407b65dd1/src/arrays/map.js#L3-L17) therefore you cannot set a domain of array of objects

I'd suggest instead creating an array with the things you want to show and use that as `x.tickValues`

```
var data = [
  { name: 'a', value: 1, count: 1 },
  { name: 'b', value: 2, count: 2 }
]
var count = data.map(function (d) { return d.count })

// and then in the x-axis
x.tickValues(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It did not work for me but I'll study D3 more in-depth because it'll help me for everything.